# How do you change user's names and email addresses?

Tags: user-profile

In SharePoint 2010, how do you change users' names and email addresses when you don't have Active Directory - when the accounts you are using are just local user accounts?

Comment: Have the same issue. I agree with the original poster. Looks like there just is no way to edit and add a email address for a local user no matter what you do. The Set -SPUser command in PowerShell just generates a ">>" with a flashing cursur when you hit return.

Answer (score 7):

> *My theory is that you can only edit that for your users are coming from an
>   Active Directory. But maybe there is
>   something else going on.*

WRONG

You can set username and email using this command from PowerShell

Set-SPUser -Identity **'yourmachine\Roberto'** -DisplayName **'Roberto'** -Email **'robertosljunior@yahoo.com.br'** -Web **http://yourmachine**

Comment: Dang, that seems too easy! :D Note that if you have many site collections you may need to make this change for each one (give the site collection URL in the `-web` option).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using local accounts instead of domain accounts, I am assuming that you have access to the server.

I would use PowerShell to accomplish the user managements tasks.

Move-SPUser is the command you would use to change user names : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx

A couple of notes:

- Even though you are using local accounts, the cmdlet still requires a full name. Instead of using domain\username use servername\username where servername is the NETBIOS name of the machine you have installed SP on
- You will likely need to use the IgnoreSID flag since you are using local accounts and do not want to query Active Directory

A sample command (I am piping the SPUser from Get-SPUser) -

```
Get-SPUser "testserver\ctester" -Web "http://testserver"| Move-SPUser -NewAlias "testserver\ctester1" -IgnoreSID
```

To modify the email address, you can use the Set-SPUser cmdlet : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607827.aspx

HTH,
Landon

Answer (score 1):

If the user will click on his/her name on the top right of the home page, the drop down will show an option for "My Settings".  If they will click on that they'll be able to change their display name and email address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob but that doesn't work on the two installations I've done so far.  None of the user's profile information is editable.  My theory is that you can only edit that for your users are coming from an Active Directory.  But maybe there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Site Actions > Site Settings > People and Groups

You will find your users in these groups.

Alternatively click on one of these groups then change the ?MembershipGroupId=X property to 0 to view all users in all groups, i.e.

http://yourserver/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  That does let me see all my users, but it doens't let me change their name or email address.

Comment: Hmm - are you a site administrator?

Comment: Or is it that after you've changed the email/name it changes back some time later?